# Facebook sdk web view issue

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login

I am facing Facebook native sdk issue. When i am trying to login Facebook in application using Facebook sdk webview.

```
let facebookLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager() 
facebookLoginManager?.loginBehavior = .web 
facebookLoginManager?.logIn(withReadPermissions: readPermissions, from: self, handler: { [unowned self] (fbLoginResult, error) in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Process error")
        } else if (fbLoginResult?.isCancelled)! {
            print("Permissions cancelled by user.")
        } else {
            print("Success")
    })
```

I given required email and password it goes to Facebook account screen. If i am waiting more than 2 seconds Facebook sdk webview automatically dismisses with error "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “googleads.g.doubleclick.net” which could put your confidential information at risk." "

Comment: Are you actively embedding any ads from `googleads.g.doubleclick.net` in that context? (Dunno if that's even possible.) If not, this is likely rather a Facebook/Google issue, and needs to be fixed on their end.

Comment: I am not using any ads in my application.

Comment: Then I guess it must be ads injected by Facebook. And either Google has/had an issue with the SSL certificate for that particular domain (several online checkers don't report any issues with it currently), or the webview has an issue with the certificate for some reason. If the issue persists (if it was a cert problem on Google's side, I'd expect them to have that fixed rather quickly), I would suggest you file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/